# No new lines in source code with Html helpers in MVC3 :-(

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using helpers like the following:

```
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login.UserName, new { @class = "adm", size = 30 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.UserName)

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.Password, new { @class = "adm" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Login.Password, new { @class = "adm", size = 30 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.Password)
```

When I look at the source code it appears in one very long line with no line breaks. Is
there any way I can use the helpers and have the source code formatted a bit better? It
is just so difficult to read when in one 300 column line?

thanks

Comment: Remember that you can always add a <br /> at the end of each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't bother about the HTML source. That's for browsers to read, not humans. But if you wanted proper formatting you could wrap them in the special `<text>` node:

```
<text>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.UserName, new { @class = "adm" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login.UserName, new { @class = "adm", size = 30 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.UserName)
</text>

<text>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.Password, new { @class = "adm" })
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Login.Password, new { @class = "adm", size = 30 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.Password)
</text>
```

The `<text>` node will not be rendered in the output. Another possibility is to directly use a `<div>` or a `<span>` because from what I can see you are applying this `adm` class manually to the label and the input whereas if you wrapped them in another node you could apply the class directly to this node and then define the `adm` rule to apply to input fields inside this wrapper node.

Comment: True. Besides...if you look at the code in a DOM inspector like the developer toolbar in a browser it organizes everything hierarchically and it becomes pretty easy to manage.